# How to implement login through Facebook or Twitter or Gmail account feature in Play Framework2.0 Application

Tags: facebook, twitter, playframework-2.0, gmail

I am working for designing a web site where I use the Play Framework web application framework. I want to give a feature for the end-users to login to my web site using Facebook, Twitter and Gmail. But how to implement the same feature in Play framework as it uses scala.html? I have searched for the same, but I got the links related to php application.  Is Facebook, Twitter, and Gmail provide APIs free of cost?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://securesocial.ws/ is answer for your question, is the Play framework plugin, you can use it for Authentication and Authorization through the Social sites. Also it supports for Java & Scala and its an active project.

Comment: Interesting! Definitely looks more popular since it's been around longer. It'd be interesting to see a comparison done between the two libraries. I may just do one myself and give an update for any future users :)

Answer (score 0):

I've successfully implemented SSO Authentication with Gmail using the [play-pac4j](https://github.com/pac4j/play-pac4j) library which also supports Facebook and Twitter.